# Sending account users daily e-mails with site updates Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am trying to set something up in my app where a daily e-mail is sent out to all users with the news posts created for their account each day.

I already have the CRON task setup, but I don't know enough about ActionMailer to figure out how to send specific info to each user...

In my app, Users belong to accounts, accounts have many users, and users have many ideas and accounts have many ideas through users.

**So if Account 1 has 3 users, Every day I want all three users to receive the new ideas in the last day via e-mail.**

I know this is complicated, but if anyone can help with a starting point it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

edited to include code from model:

```
    class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    has_many :ideas, :through => :users

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
    has_many :ideas, :dependent => :destroy
```

I basically want to send this feed from the index page to each user in a daily e-mail:

```
    <strong>Here are some of your colleagues recent ideas:</strong>
    <% @ideas.each do |idea| %> #@ideas = Account.ideas
    <% if idea.created_at > 4.hours.ago %>
    <table class="microposts" summary="User microposts">
    <tr>
    <td class="micropost">
<span class="ideatitle"><%= idea.title %></span><br />
<span class="ideacontent"><%= idea.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
    Conceived <%= time_ago_in_words(idea.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
    </td>
    <td>
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 11):

It's going to be something as follows (can't get specific without code):

`daily.rake` - your rake task called through `cron` daily

```
 namespace :daily do
   desc "run daily tasks"
   task :daily, :needs => :environment do
     Account.each do |account|
       account.users.each do |user|
       UserMailer.deliver_daily_email(user)
     end
   end
 end
```

`user_mailer.rb` - Your action mailer to send the actual email

```
 UserMailer < ActiveMailer::Base
   def daily_email(user)
     @recipients  = "#{user.email}"
     @from        = "my@email"
     headers         "Reply-to" => "my@email"
     @subject     = "Your daily message"
     @sent_on     = Time.now

     @body[:user] = user
   end
 end
```

`daily_email.text.html.erb` - The actual content of the email

```
 <h2>Hi <%=h @user.name %></h2>
 You like:
 <ul>
   <% @user.account.ideas.each do |idea| %>
     <li><%=h idea.title %></li>
   <% end %>
 </ul>

 -sincerely, the mailer server
```

Hope this gives you a good idea of how this should all be configured.  Let me know if anything is confusing here.  Enjoy!

**[Edit]**

As noted by Josh Pinter below, you'll probably only want to send the user new ideas (either created in the last 24 hours, or track which ideas the user has seen and preclude those from e-mail). You can do this by a scope in `idea.rb`

```
scope :recent, -> { where("created_at < ", 1.day.ago) }
```

or

```
# Note, you'll need to create and maintain a `viewed_at` column
scope :unviewed, -> { where(viewed_at: nil) }
```

Then, for each user, you can check

`ideas = user.ideas.recent.any?` and only send the e-mail if there are `recent` or `unviewed` ideas. After you send the e-mail, you could set viewed at by running `ideas.update_all(viewed_at: Time.now)`.

Comment: That's a great start thanks. I guess I'm just confused about how I can send each user all of the ideas from the account. Doesn't the above only send each user their own ideas?

Comment: I'm confused about your specific structure `users have many ideas and accounts have many ideas through users`, doesn't this mean that users have ideas, not accounts.  Can you post your activemodel records and this will be more obvious :)

Comment: Thanks so much guys. You've really saved me on this one. It's been a long couple of days and I sort of hit a wall with this, as ActionMailer is brand new to me.

Comment: Probably want to add a filter to only include ideas that have been created in the last 24 hours, or whatever, like `@user.account.ideas.where( "created_at >= ?", Time.now - 24.hours ).each do |idea|`